# /dev/mapper device remains after stopping cryptsetup unit

Tags: linux, systemd, cryptsetup

This is an `ArchLinux` box and I can't cleanly stop an encrypted container by means of `systemd`. I have to additionally issue `cryptsetup close`. Is this misconfiguration or a bug?

`/etc/crypttab`:

```
myprivate /media/il/USBHDD/A_U_T_O_R_U_N/TrueCrypt/volume.tc none tcrypt,noauto
```

`~/.xprofile`:

```
systemd-gnome-ask-password-agent &
```

`/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/mapper/myprivate /media/il/myprivate auto    noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-gvfs-hide    0    0
```

journal messages `systemctl stop systemd-cryptsetup@myprivate` :

```
il systemd[1]: Unmounting /media/il/myprivate...
il systemd[4862]: media-il-myprivate.mount: Succeeded.
il systemd[19968]: media-il-myprivate.mount: Succeeded.
il ntfs-3g[29489]: Unmounting /dev/mapper/myprivate (MYPRIVATE)
il systemd[1]: media-il-myprivate.mount: Succeeded.
il systemd[1]: Unmounted /media/il/myprivate.
```

Commands:

```
[root@il ~]# systemctl stop systemd-cryptsetup@myprivate
[root@il ~]# umount /media/il/USBHDD
umount: /media/il/USBHDD: target is busy.
[root@il ~]# lsof | grep /media/il/USBHDD
[root@il ~]#
[root@il ~]# cryptsetup close myprivate
[root@il ~]# umount /media/il/USBHDD
[root@il ~]#
```